# Wrong Data Received from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the data from Firebase, but when I debug my app I can see that the app has found the key I put, but I received no data on the value:

```
 DatabaseReference taxiref = childRef.child(chapa);
 taxiref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         Sesion.taxis.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Taxi.class));
     }

     @Override
     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

     }
});
```

As you can see in the following code, that my structure from Firebase:

```
"taxis" : {
  "bbb222" : {
    "año" : 1998,
    "modelo" : "Gol",
    "ubicaciones" : {
      "u1" : {
        "fecha" : "20-12-2016 12:30",
        "latitud" : 31231231,
        "longitud" : 2131241
      },
      "u2" : {
        "fecha" : "20-12-2016 12:31",
        "latitud" : 31231232,
        "longitud" : 2131243
      }
    }
  },
```

And as you can see on the following image when I debugged the code the key I got is correct, but I didn't receive any value, could somebody help me with that?

[image: img]

Here its the taxi.java class:

```
public class Taxi {

    private String año;
    private String modelo;
    private String chapaTaxi;
    private LinkedList<Ubicaciones> ubicaciones;

    public void diagramarRecorrido() {
        for (Ubicaciones u : getUbicaciones()) {
            u.ubicarMapa();
        }
    }

    public String getAño() {
        return año;
    }

    public void setAño(String año) {
        this.año = año;
    }

    public String getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }

    public void setModelo(String modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }

    public String getChapaTaxi() {
        return chapaTaxi;
    }

    public void setChapaTaxi(String chapaTaxi) {
        this.chapaTaxi = chapaTaxi;
    }

    public LinkedList<Ubicaciones> getUbicaciones() {
        return ubicaciones;
    }

    public void setUbicaciones(LinkedList<Ubicaciones> ubicaciones) {
        this.ubicaciones = ubicaciones;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post links to images of JSON or code. Instead post the actual code, error messages and JSON as text. You can easily get the JSON by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having these  as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: ok sorry about that, letme paste the JSON part.

Comment: Show `Taxi.java`, please

Comment: I just added the class mate

Comment: I could be wrong, but you might need an empty constructor for `public Taxi () { }`

Comment: Either that, or Firebase has no `chapaTaxi` field

Comment: The thing its I never get the data in order to match the class, if you see on the image when I debug, I recieve no data from firebase

Comment: look at the logcat / android device monitor, check if you got `permission denied` error or any other error string from the firebase after the onDataChange is triggered

Comment: in your code: `childRef.child(chapa);`. What is `childRef` and `chapa`?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys my bad, childRef was a variable:

```
private static DatabaseReference childRef= ref.child("taxis");
```

and that was the problem as you can see the child its taxis but I had Taxis thats why I never got any results from the firebase, thanks to all for all your help.